# Implementing AlphaBlend in Print using C++

Tags: c++, windows, printing, gdi

I want to use alpha-blending for my printer DC.

However, in the printer driver, type 3 does not support `AlphaBlend()`. Starting with type 4, `AlphaBlend()` is supported.

But I have to use alpha-blending for both types 3 and 4 to make the image transparent and then print it.

The reason I insist on this is because it's the fastest.

Therefore, I want to implement my own `AlphaBlend()` using GDI APIs (`BitBlt`, `StrectDIBits()`, etc) to support alpha-blending in type 3.

But, I am wondering, how can I implement alpha-blending on my own?

Has anyone implemented their own `AlphaBlend()`?

Comment: What is **type 3 and type 4**?

Comment: Alpha blend is just mixing two colors in some proportion. The formula is simple too, which you can find online.

Comment: You tagged the question with [tag:gdi+], so are you open to using GDI+? It has its own alpha-blending capabilities. If you want to use only GDI, then remove the GDI+ tag from your question.

Comment: You cannot implement alpha blending using `BitBlt` with any of the [ternary raster operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/ternary-raster-operations). That's why `AlphaBlend` exists.

Comment: Type 3 and 4 refer to the driver type in print server properties.
In an environment where GDI+ cannot be used, GDI must be used.
I need to implement the same functionality as AlphaBlend in GDI, but I'm having difficulty with this.

Comment: You are having difficulty because you cannot do this. `BitBlt` applies the ternary raster operation to each individual color channel. Per-pixel alpha blending would require that you used the alpha channel to modulate the color channels, which `BitBlt` cannot do. You're going to have to read the raw memory, do the math, and write back to memory. The GDI cannot help you with this.